# Update column in sqlite table from value of column in same table

Tags: sqlite

I have searched and found loads of examples but am still struggling to make this work.

I have the following table in SQLite:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA;

ID|USER|NAME|PARENT
1|User1|SomeName|-1
2|User1|SomeOtherName|1
3|User2|SomeName|-1
4|User2|SomeOtherName|-1
```

The PARENT for ID 2 with NAME of SomeOtherName is ID 1 - This is correct.

The PARENT for ID 4 with the NAME of SomeOtherName is ID -1 - This is incorrect. It should be ID 3.

I have many incorrect records like that (all with the same NAME of SomeOtherName and a PARENT of -1).

The column that ties them together is USER.

I need to update all the incorrect records with the correct parent ID.

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
DROP TABLE orphans;

CREATE TEMP TABLE orphans as
    SELECT TableA.id, TableA.user, TableA.name FROM TableA WHERE TableA.name = 'SomeOtherName' AND TableA.parent = -1;

UPDATE TableA
SET parent = (  SELECT TableA.id
                        FROM TableA
                        INNER JOIN orphans
                        ON TableA.name = 'SomeName' AND orphans.user = TableA.user
                )
WHERE TableA.user IN (  SELECT TableA.user
                                FROM TableA WHERE TableA.name = 'SomeOtherName' AND TableA.parent = -1 )
;
```

I just can't seem to get it right. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, sqlite has *very* limited capabilities for complex queries in the `UPDATE` statement. You can not use more than one table, and I haven't found a way to reference a value from the current row from within a subquery.

Instead I've come up with this:

```
SELECT id, user, name,
  CASE name = 'SomeOtherName' AND parent = -1
  WHEN 1 THEN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM TableA A2
    WHERE A1.user = A2.user
    AND A2.name != 'SomeOtherName'
  ) ELSE parent END AS parent
FROM TableA A1;
```

This *should* be the data you want, right? You can write that to a temporary table, and feed the data back into your original table from there. This feeding back can be done using `REPLACE` if you have unique keys, or using `DETELTE` followed by `INSERT` if not. I've created [an example of the latter on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/1a5ba/22).

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped tremendously. The only change I had to make to the query when using it on my live system was to name the column parent1 at the end of the tmp table and then insert parent1 into TableA as parent instead. Change can be seen on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/1a5ba/9

Answer (score 1):

Late reply of course, but I DO believe this can be accomplished without temp tables. Just using selects in proper way.
The code below works for me in a similar table:

```
UPDATE TableA SET PARENT = (
            SELECT ID
            FROM TableA AS T
            WHERE T.NAME = 'SomeName' AND T.USER = TableA.USER
        )
WHERE ID IN (
            SELECT ID
            FROM TableA
            WHERE TableA.NAME = 'SomeOtherName' AND TableA.PARENT = -1
            );
```

Comment: Did you do this with sqlite? It doesn't seem to like "AS T"

Comment: Yes, I use SQLite 3.5.1 and this works perfectly fine.
Sorry, didn't notice your question right away.